SQL SERVER - rellenar con las horas restantes en consulta para devolver 24 registros por dia
como podria realizar una consulta que me devuelva 24 registros por día aunque solo tenga una registro solo 1 registro por dia?
Ej. Tabla
FechaHora        Valor
----------------------
1/1/2024 15:00   100

Consulta a obtener
FechaHora        Valor
----------------------
1/1/2024 0:00    Null
1/1/2024 1:00    Null
1/1/2024 2:00    Null
1/1/2024 3:00    Null
1/1/2024 4:00    Null
1/1/2024 5:00    Null
1/1/2024 6:00    Null
1/1/2024 7:00    Null
1/1/2024 8:00    Null
1/1/2024 9:00    Null
1/1/2024 10:00   Null
1/1/2024 11:00   Null
1/1/2024 12:00   Null
1/1/2024 13:00   Null
1/1/2024 14:00   Null
1/1/2024 15:00    100
1/1/2024 16:00   Null
1/1/2024 17:00   Null
1/1/2024 18:00   Null
1/1/2024 19:00   Null
1/1/2024 20:00   Null
1/1/2024 21:00   Null
1/1/2024 22:00   Null
1/1/2024 23:00   Null

Saludos y gracias por la ayuda

Siguiendo las mismas idea planteadas en la respuesta a la pregunta ¿cómo agregar fechas faltantes entre dos fechas en sql server?, necesitas lo siguiente:

Un CTE que genere números, en este caso del 0 al 23, que serán utilizados como hora en el resultado final, por ejemplo:
select top 24 ROW_NUMBER() over (order by (select null)) - 1 as Hora from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS

Pero también valdría algo manual, como
select 0 union select 1 union select 2 ... union select 23

Lo importante es tener 24 registros con números del 0 al 23.

Otro CTE que obtenga, de la tabla original, las distintas fechas que serán parte del resultado. Esto porque tu pregunta solo muestra un registro, pero no aclara si lo necesitas para una sola fecha o varias, he preferido generalizar la respuesta. Si es una sola fecha, puedes simplificar esta parte.

Hacer el producto cartesiano de los dos conjuntos de datos anteriores, y para cada registro resultante, sumar la hora del primer CTE a la fecha del segundo CTE.

Finalmente, con este conjunto de datos, hacer left join a la tabla original, para obtener las coincidencias de los registros que si existen en la tabla.


Colocando todas las piezas juntas, más un primer CTE que simula la tabla, tendríamos:
with
Tabla as (
select CAST('20240101 15:00' as datetime) FechaHora, 100 as valor
)
,
Hora as (
select top 24 ROW_NUMBER() over (order by (select null)) - 1 as Hora from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
)
,
Fecha as (
select distinct CAST(FechaHora as date) Fecha from Tabla
)
,
FechaYHora as (
select DATEADD(Hour, Hora, cast(Fecha as datetime)) FechaHora
  from Fecha 
       cross join Hora
)
select FechaYHora.FechaHora, Tabla.Valor
  from FechaYHora
       left join Tabla on Tabla.FechaHora = FechaYHora.FechaHora

Da como resultado:
FechaHora               Valor
----------------------- -----------
2024-01-01 00:00:00.000 NULL
2024-01-01 01:00:00.000 NULL
2024-01-01 02:00:00.000 NULL
2024-01-01 03:00:00.000 NULL
2024-01-01 04:00:00.000 NULL
2024-01-01 05:00:00.000 NULL
2024-01-01 06:00:00.000 NULL
2024-01-01 07:00:00.000 NULL
2024-01-01 08:00:00.000 NULL
2024-01-01 09:00:00.000 NULL
2024-01-01 10:00:00.000 NULL
2024-01-01 11:00:00.000 NULL
2024-01-01 12:00:00.000 NULL
2024-01-01 13:00:00.000 NULL
2024-01-01 14:00:00.000 NULL
2024-01-01 15:00:00.000 100
2024-01-01 16:00:00.000 NULL
2024-01-01 17:00:00.000 NULL
2024-01-01 18:00:00.000 NULL
2024-01-01 19:00:00.000 NULL
2024-01-01 20:00:00.000 NULL
2024-01-01 21:00:00.000 NULL
2024-01-01 22:00:00.000 NULL
2024-01-01 23:00:00.000 NULL

(24 rows affected)

